# Conditional string generation in R (for loop + if/else)

Tags: r, loops, boolean-expression

Afraid I can't paste a code example as my dataset is sensitive.

After some issues with our source files we realised that our source file is inconsistent with allele coding and need to alter it, the first step in that is dropping the redundant column value (sometimes it's `REF`, sometimes `ALT1`), the third value, `A1` is always used, all three are characters, and `POSITION` is a string.

Given the number of rows involved I've tried to set up a loop as follows:

- Go to next row
- Concatenate new identifier using `A1` and whichever of `REF` and `ALT1` does not equal `A1`

Looks simple enought in theory, but just won't behave; on inspection it appears to correctly catch the first instance of the first line but not the others.

Is there a glaring mistake I've made somewhere? Thanks.

```
    # NOTE: reversed in order to match mapping file formatting (equiv. to REF_ALT)
for (i in 1:nrow(Chr1_results.dt)){

if(Chr1_results.dt[i,]$A1 != Chr1_results.dt[i,]$ALT1){
  Chr1_results.dt[i,]$POSITION <- paste(Chr1_results.dt[i,]$ID, Chr1_results.dt[i,]$A1, Chr1_results.dt[i,]$ALT1, sep = "_")
} else{
  Chr1_results.dt[i,]$POSITION <- paste(Chr1_results.dt[i,]$ID, Chr1_results.dt[i,]$A1, Chr1_results.dt[i,]$REF, sep = "_")
}
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We don't need to see your actual sensitive data; you can include fake data as long as it clearly demonstrates what the problem is.

Comment: If you cannot disclose your data then please shae some dummy data that gives us some idea of it, e.g. like
Chr1_results.dt <- data.frame(A1 = 1:5, 
                              ALT1 = c(11,2,3,4,15), 
                              REF = c(1,22,23,4,5), 
                              ID = letters[1:5],
                              POSITION = character(5), 
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)